# how to get drawerOpen() to stack navigator screen Options

Tags: react-native, stack-navigator

i have this stack navigator:

```
const StackNavigator = () => (
<Stack.Navigator headerMode="screen" navigationOptions screenOptions={ss}>
    <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={MainScreen} headerMode="screen" />...............
```

and i have object of screen options:

```
const ss = {
cardStyleInterpolator: CardStyleInterpolators.forHorizontalIOS,
gestureEnabled: true,
gestureDirection: "horizontal",
headerTitleAlign: "center",
headerHideShadow: true,
headerTintColor: "red",
headerStyle: {
    borderBottomWidth: 0.5,
    borderColor: "white",
    backgroundColor: "#1d2731",
},

headerTitleStyle: {
    color: "white",
},
headerLeft: () => <AnimateHamburger navigation={navigation} />,
};
```

no when i get inside the component AnimatedHamburger

i dont get the props of openDrawer ...i get "...
navigation.openDrawer is not function....................

the AnimateHamburger component:

```
const AnimateHamburger = ({ navigation }) => {
console.log(navigation);
const isDrawerOpen = useIsDrawerOpen();

const toggleMenu = () => {
    navigation.openDrawer();
};

return (
    <View style={styles.icon}>
        <Icon
            style={styles.icon}
            onPress={toggleMenu}
            name={isDrawerOpen ? "enter" : "bars"}
            type={isDrawerOpen ? "antdesign" : "font-awesome"}
            color="black"
            size={30}
        />
    </View>
);
 };
```

**PLEASE help me how can i get the navigation props to toggle my drawer from the AnimateHamburger component**

Answer (score 0):

If you receiving `openDrawer is not a function` that's probably you are trying to access this method in a nested navigator which don't know about the parent drawer navigator. You can access drawer methods with `DrawerAction` from `react-navigation` take a look here:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-actions

And use it like this:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/#navigator-specific-methods-are-available-in-the-navigators-nested-inside